# Is there a way to get the current rotation of a object in VPython?

Tags: python, object, vector, rotation, vpython

I have a object that I want to get the current rotation of, but I cannot seem to find any information on how to do this. The only way I could think of was to add a variable onto the object and change it exactly how much I rotate the object.

```
test.rotate(test.rotational_velocity * dt, vec(0, 0, 1))
test.angle += test.rotational_velocity * dt
```

Is there any better method to get the current rotation of an object in VPython?

Comment: I think using own `text.angle` can be the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on vectors at glowscript.org (click "Help"):

diff_angle(A,B) = A.diff_angle(B), the angle between two vectors, in radians

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can get it using the `axis` attribute of a 3D object. As the object rotates, its axis also rotates with it. E.g. in your case, you can get the axis using:

```
test.axis
```